# "The past hours" or "The passed hours" which one to use?

Tags: expression-choice

Imagine the following situation :

[image: scene]

You've arranged a meeting with a colleague at a specific time ( say at **6:00 PM** ), but he didn't show up until **8:00 PM** ( **2 hours** have passed ).
If I were to refer to those hours I spent waiting for my colleague to show up ( **the two hours** ), what should I call them ? ( The past hours or The passed hours ).

[**Ngram :**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=past%20hours%2C%20passed%20hours&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpast%20hours%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpast%20hours%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPast%20hours%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpast%20Hours%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPAST%20HOURS%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPast%20Hours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpassed%20hours%3B%2Cc0)

[image: ngram]

Comment: After two hours it should be a frowny face on your diagram, not a smiley face. I would call them 'spent hours' because they are never coming back again.

Comment: @NigelJ Thank you so much .( picture updated :-D )

Comment: The past tense of "pass" is "passed".  Do you intend to refer to hours in the past, or to hours that have passed?

Comment: @HotLicks I would like to refer to the hours that have passed.

Comment: Neither would be used by a competent native speaker.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  What do you think about Bread's answer?Thank you.

Comment: His answer should be a close-vote. 98+% of people would say 'the two hours I've just wasted waiting for you' or a close paraphrase in this situation. With a better example,  'the past hours' is far more likely than 'the passed hours' as [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+past+hours%2Cthe+passed+hours&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20past%20hours%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggest.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  what do you suggest?

Comment: ... 'wasted hours'. But this is now revealed as off-topic on ELU.

Comment: *Wasted* hours, *lost* hours, *useless* hours, *misspent* hours, *uneventful* hours, *boring* hours. Any of those is better than either "past" or (even worse) "passed."

Comment: @JasonBassford If this comment were an answer, I would defensively accept it.  Thank you so much, you are AWESOME .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two different words that are homophones (soundalikes) but they function differently grammatically. In the phrase, I have been waiting for the past two hours, past is adverbial (when did the two hours occur? In the past) "passed two hours" is an inversion of two hours *have* passed, meaning it is a verb form of the verb to pass, as in the passing of time. So Although two hours have passed, you have been waiting for the past two hours. Past in this second part does not mean the specific hours that went by, but answers *when* the time was you were waiting. And yes, native English speakers might say something like that. Not, "passed two hours," but "past two hours."

Answer (score -1):

The **Passed hours** is more specific than the **Past hours**, because all hours in the past are the Past hours. But the Passed hours are the hours in question: the hours spent waiting.

Why? Because those are the *specific* hours in which you personally passed your time waiting for your colleague.